# Laravel database collection property of non object in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-collection

I have an issue with looping through a Laravel collection in a Blade component. The error I get is the following.

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.

First of all, I query the database to get a list of categories with their children.

```
ContentCategory::with('children')
    ->whereNull('parent_id')
    ->orderby('name')
    ->get();
```

I have a Laravel Blade component that displays the Select2 dropdown list.

```
<x-select2 name="user_categories" :list="$user_categories">
    <x-slot name="label">
        @cruds(user.fields.user_categories.text)
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="helper">
        @cruds(user.fields.user_categories.helper)
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="select_all">
        @globals(select_all)
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="deselect_all">
        @globals(deselect_all)
    </x-slot>
</x-select2>
```

When I loop through the collection and try to access a property of the collection, I get an undefined property.

```
@foreach($list as $parent)
    <option value="{{ $parent->id }}" >{{ $parent->name }}</option>
    @if (isset($parent->children) && $p->children->count())
        @foreach($parent->children as $children_id => $children_title)
            <option value="{{ $children_id }}" {{ $isSelected($children_id) ? 
                'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $children_title }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

[image: The following image is the collection of data]

The error is as follows.

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
> /var/www/html/trybz/resources/views/components/select2.blade.php)

[image: where the error is occuring]

Comment: Please, edit your original question as you say "the error is `name` is undefined" but here at the bottom you say and show that `id` is undefined. Can you share what `$p` has/is in that loop ? Also, if you are not using `$index`, why do you define `@foreach($list as $index => $p)` instead of `@foreach($list as $p)` (and personal recommendation, define `$p` as `$model` or whatever, but not `$j` or anything like that.

Comment: No matter what attribute I try to access id or name I get the same error. $p is just a variable I use in the foreach loop. Doesn't matter if index is there or not I still get the error

Comment: But what is the content of `$p` in the loop ? If you see the image you shared, we can't see the left side, it should have more info about what `$p` has in that loop. Clearly `$p` is not what you expected it to be. Something is off.